# Generating time interval array in python

Tags: python-3.x

to generate a  array  with time delta  within two specific dates

Comment: hello, please clarify or add more examples

Comment: numpy doesn't know how many days there are in a month.
if an answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
year = 2018
month = 1
day = 1
time_obj = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, 0, 0)
i=1
date_dict={}
while time_obj.year < 2021:
    date_dict[i]={}
    date_dict[i] = {}
    date_dict[i]['date'] = i
    date_dict[i]["year:"] = time_obj.strftime("%Y")
    date_dict[i]["month:"] = time_obj.strftime("%m")
    date_dict[i]["day:"] = time_obj.strftime("%d")
    date_dict[i]["Start time:"] = time_obj.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    time_obj += timedelta(minutes=59)
    time = time_obj.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    time_obj += timedelta(minutes=1)
    date_dict[i]["End time:"] = time
    i+=1
print(date_dict)
```

Hope it helped